# HTML - Select Box with price alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a select with amounts of cash and want to align the dollar symbols with numbers. 
like this:

```
$    0,00
$   10,00
$  100,00
$ 1000,00
```

I already tried the html tag "dir=rtl". But does not work for the symbol goes right along with the numbers

**EDIT:**

my code:

```
<select name="valor2" style="width: 150px;" dir="rtl">
                <option value="9999999">Qualquer um</option>
                <option value="50000">R$50.000,00</option>
                <option value="100000">R$100.000,00</option>
                <option value="200000">R$200.000,00</option>
                <option value="500000">R$500.000,00</option>'
                <option value="800000">R$800.000,00</option>
                <option value="1000000">R$1.000.000,00</option>
                <option value="2000000">R$2.000.000,00</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: You would probably need to use JavaScript to align two different types of chars to different sides. I actually don't even know if that's possible. Also, on an unrelated note, assuming by "dollar" you mean USD, you should use `.` instead of `,` to denote decimals. We use `,` as a thousands separator.

Comment: can you edit the actual HTML or is it dynamically generated?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could paste the actual HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

You need to seperate the text into seperate blocks:

```
<div style="width:100px;">
        <div style="float:left">$</div>
        <div style="position:relative;text-align:right;">1000.00</div>
        <div style="float:left">$</div>
        <div style="position:relative;text-align:right;">100.00</div>
    </div>
```

That way you can float and align however you like.

Comment: i used select box. No divs. :)

Comment: Oh, wow.  I thought you meant a checkbox.  You're right.  This won't work.  Sorry.

Comment: Heh..  Well, on the other hand, you could change your page to handle radio buttons instead...

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just space it out manually ?

```
<select name="valor2" style="width: 150px;" dir="rtl">
  <option value="9999999">Qualquer um</option>
  <option value="50000">R$   50.000,00</option>
  <option value="100000">R$  100.000,00</option>
  <option value="200000">R$  200.000,00</option>
  <option value="500000">R$  500.000,00</option>'
  <option value="800000">R$  800.000,00</option>
  <option value="1000000">R$ 1.000.000,00</option>
  <option value="2000000">R$ 2.000.000,00</option>
</select>
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: It does not work. I tried to use the space in html ("") but does not get aligned.

Comment: What about using `code`&nbsp;`code` ? Does that work?